# Snowflake row generator to insert random adhoc data in table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table t1 with one record.

```
name    Reg address
david   12  a23 Carl Marx
```

Now I need to create 100 record using row generator and insert that into the table.

so that table t1 has 101 record now with 100 row of adhoc data in the table.

I can write a query like

```
Insert into t1 from
select randstr(5, random()) name, 
       uniform(1, 10, random(12)) reg,
       randstr(20, random()) address
  from table(generator(rowcount => 10));
```

However I have 40 table like t1 with 30 plus column.
So I need to use the datatype of table column to generate adhoc data.

Is there a better way to use the datatype of table to generate adhoc data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited with usage instructions below) The Gods of SQL Purity may scorn me for this answer but I propose creating a Javascript UDF that takes the output of GET_DDL, parses the results and returns to a SQL statement, which you can then copy/paste and run.

Here is one such UDF which worked against the table I tried it on by `select prepare_seed_stmt('my_tbl', get_ddl('table', 'my_tbl'));`

Pay close attention to the `expressions` object to make sure it does what you want   and since many datatypes are missing (like VARIANT, etc)

```
create or replace function prepare_seed_stmt(t string, ddl string)
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
const regex = /^\t(.*?) (.*?)(?: |,|\n)/gm;

const expressions = {
    "string": "randstr(5, random()) ",
    "number": "uniform(1, 10, random(12))",
    "object": "object_construct(randstr(5, random()), uniform(1, 10, random(12)))",
    "ts_ntz": "dateadd(second, uniform(-1e6, 1e6, random()), current_timestamp::timestamp_ntz)",
    "array": "array_construct(uniform(1, 10, random(12))"
}

const mapping = {
    "FLOAT": "number",
    "NUMBER": "number",
    "VARCHAR": "string",
    "OBJECT": "object",
    "ARRAY": "array",
    "TIMESTAMP_NTZ": "ts_ntz",
}

let m;

let sql = `insert into ${T} from\nselect \n`;

while ((m = regex.exec(DDL)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    sql += `${expressions[mapping[m[2].replace(/\(|\)|[0-9]/g, '')]]} ${m[1]},\n`
}

sql = sql.slice(0, -2)

sql += "\nfrom table(generator(rowcount => 10));"

return sql
$$
;
```

**Usage**

Say you have a table 'foo' and you want to generate a SQL `insert into foo from select <for_each_column_an_expression_for_random_data> from table(generator(rowcount => 10))`

FOO is defined as follows

```
select get_ddl('table', 'foo');

--returns: 
create or replace TABLE FOO (
    a NUMBER(38,0),
    b VARCHAR(16777216),
    c VARCHAR(16777216),
    d VARCHAR(16777216),
    e TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9),
    f VARCHAR(16777216),
    g FLOAT,
    h OBJECT,
    i OBJECT,
    j OBJECT,
    k OBJECT,
    l VARCHAR(16777216),
    m VARCHAR(16777216),
    n OBJECT,
    o OBJECT,
    p VARCHAR(16777216),
    q NUMBER(38,0),
    r VARCHAR(16777216),
    s NUMBER(38,0),
    t TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) DEFAULT CAST(CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS TIMESTAMP_TZ(9))) AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9))
);
```

Run `select prepare_seed_sql('foo', get_ddl('table', 'foo'));` to return the following, which can then be executed.

```
insert into foo from
select 
uniform(1, 10, random(12)) a,
randstr(5, random())  b,
randstr(5, random())  c,
randstr(5, random())  d,
dateadd(second, uniform(-1e6, 1e6, random()), current_timestamp::timestamp_ntz) e,
randstr(5, random())  f,
uniform(1, 10, random(12)) g,
object_construct(randstr(5, random()), uniform(1, 10, random(12))) h,
object_construct(randstr(5, random()), uniform(1, 10, random(12))) i,
object_construct(randstr(5, random()), uniform(1, 10, random(12))) j,
object_construct(randstr(5, random()), uniform(1, 10, random(12))) k,
randstr(5, random())  l,
randstr(5, random())  m,
object_construct(randstr(5, random()), uniform(1, 10, random(12))) n,
object_construct(randstr(5, random()), uniform(1, 10, random(12))) o,
randstr(5, random())  p,
uniform(1, 10, random(12)) q,
randstr(5, random())  r,
uniform(1, 10, random(12)) s,
dateadd(second, uniform(-1e6, 1e6, random()), current_timestamp::timestamp_ntz) t
from table(generator(rowcount => 10));
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for this beautiful UDF. however when I try Select prepare_seed_stmt('t1','string');.. it is returning insert into t1 from select from table(generator(rowcount => 10)); and by god I am not able to figure where it is missing the expression in while loop .. I am getting hope.. Please help..

Comment: The second argument needs to the the result of get_ddl() for a table.  I added an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It is working the only issue now is for any table when I run this .. It is not getting the last column in insert statement

Comment: I just updated regex in the UDF, so if you update yours to reflect that it should fix the issue with the last column.